# DBFS not showing on databricks UI

Tags: azure-databricks

I am new to Azure. I am trying to mount blob storage containers to databricks file system. I have followed few tutorials, but while not able to find DBFS on databricks UI to upload files.

I tried below code

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = {"<conf-key>":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to `Enable DBFS File Browser` from `Workspace settings`.

To enable it, go to `Admin console` and then go to `Workspace settings`.

[image]

As shown in below image you need to `Enable DBFS File Browser`.

[image]

Now you will find DBFS on databricks UI.